# Differentiability of $f(x+y) = \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $(-1, 1)$ such that for all $x, y \in (-1, 1)$,

$$f(x+y) = \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}$$

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$

(i) Show that $f$ is differentiable on $(-1, 1)$.

(ii) If $f'(0) = \pi/2$, find the explicit expression of $f(x)$.

Comment: These two duplicates are identical, and IMO should be merged. This one has a more detailed answer, the other one has an ok accepted answer as well, but that question is higher voted. In light of those points I am inclined to merge this to the other post. Letting this comment sit here for a while in case somebody disagrees and/or wants to raise a point I missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To establish $f(0)$:

$$f(x+y) = \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}\implies f(x+0) = \frac{f(x)+f(0)}{1-f(x)f(0)}$$

$$\implies f(x)\left\{1-f(x)f(0)\right\}=f(x)+f(0)\implies f(0)=0$$

To find the derivative:

$$\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h}= \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{f(x)+f(h)}{1-f(x)f(h)}-f(x)\right)=\frac{(1+f(x)^2)}{1-f(x)f(h)}\frac{f(h)}{h}$$

$$=\frac{(1+f(x)^2)}{1-f(x)f(h)}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\to \frac{(1+f(x)^2)}{1-f(x)f(0)}f'(0)\text{ as }h\to0$$

So:

$$f'(x)=f'(0)\cdot\left(1+f(x)^2\right)$$

If $f'(0)=\pi/2$, then:

$$f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1+f(x)^2\right)\implies \frac{f'}{1+f^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \tan^{-1}f(x)-\tan^{-1}f(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}x\implies f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$$

Comment: Is there something wrong in the 4th line. Shouldn't it be $(1 + f(x)^2)$?

Comment: @TheYellow yep thats correct, will amend

Comment: May I ask if this is a 3-D function or 2-D (function of 2 variables or 1 variable)? Also, to find the derivative at$ (-1, 1)$, should I compute $f'(-1)$ or $f'(-1 + 1)$?

Comment: It's a function defined on $(-1,1)$, which is a 1d interval - it's a function of one variable. It's asking you to show differentiability on the interval $(-1,1)$, not at a point.

Comment: Is there a particular name for this class of functions? This function seems rather different from the ones I usually see.

Comment: @TheYellow, you seem to confuse interval $(-1,1) = \{x\in\Bbb R\,|\, -1<x<1\}$ with ordered pair $(-1,1)\in\Bbb R^2$. This function is just a scaled tangens, nothing unusual about it.

Comment: Depends on what you mean - if you're talking about the structure of the question that leads to solving for the function, you could say that it's *defined by a functional equation*.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!